# Texture not appearing via stb_image

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I have been working on a new project in C++ using GLFW for a OpenGL wrapper, and using the stb_image.h tool to load images.

I load the images using the following snippet:

```
this->width = width;
this->height = height;
int bpp;

unsigned char* image = stbi_load(("./res/textures/"+fileName).c_str(), &width, &height, &bpp, STBI_rgb_alpha);

if (image == nullptr) std::cerr << "Unable to load texture: " + fileName << std::endl;

glGenTextures(1, &id);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

if(bpp == 3) glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
else if (bpp == 4) glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
stbi_image_free(image);
```

And I render the texture via:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture->id);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2i(0, 0); glVertex3i(0, 0, -5);
glTexCoord2i(0, 1); glVertex3i(0, 1, -5);
glTexCoord2i(1, 1); glVertex3i(1, 1, -5);
glTexCoord2i(1, 0); glVertex3i(1, 0, -5);
glEnd();
```

I am swapping buffers, polling events, and have set the various color bits with glfwWindowHint()

To little avail.
When I run, I simply receive the following result:

[image: white untextured quad]

Comment: What platform are you on? I think there is some issue with OSX and immediate mode - as in it doesn't support it out the box because its deprecated.

Comment: I don't really know fixed pipeline stuff but usually `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);` would be called before `glBindTexture..`

Comment: Also have you checked that there is anything in your image array?

Comment: Working on Windows. Active textures doesn't seem to be a functionality in GLFW ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)` before `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture->id)`. So, your last code should look like:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture->id);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(0, 0, -5);
glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(0, 1, -5);
glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(1, 1, -5);
glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(1, 0, -5);
glEnd();
```

Also, [`glActiveTexture(...)`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glActiveTexture.xml), does not have anything to do with GLFW. It is part of opengl.

Comment: `GL_TEXTURE0` is the default value for the active texture. So this call is only needed if the active texture was previously set to a different value.